# How to specify Item Price and Item Image/Icon in facebook credits?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Well, I could not implement the buy_item pay dialog, while the [existing problem](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9633693/implementing-facebook-credits-app-not-responding-signed-request-parsing-error) is resolved, I wanted to know how to specify the item price and icon in the payments box like the one of the developer did.

[image]

I guess there is something to do with **order_info** but none of the examples have mentioned price or icon.

Least to say, [this link](https://github.com/facebook/credits-api-sample) was refered by some of the questions which has nothing but some adobe assets :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have updated this long back.

I am not sure how I wasted so much time when every thing is there in the tutorial. I think either I didnt not follwed the tutorial or the tutorial is scattered a lot thus, I missed it.

Its given in the [api docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games_payments/fulfillment). We just need to send back those details in the **callback**.

Look at Developer response section in the documentation and there it is. We got to send the item info (price, image icon) back to Facebook in the callback function